# Profiler output data

Tags: magento2, csv, profiler

Who can explain to me about **data output** in **profiler report** in **csv** format? I have the next data but don't know what is mean.

```
cache_frontend_create,0.023024,0.011512,2,"2,560,880",0
magento,8.667415,8.667415,1,"79,862,304","38,649,856"

magento->EVENT:core_collection_abstract_load_before,0.070687,0.070687,1,"273,448",0
```

Comment: Reading with header will make sense. Just try to get the first row which should be the header

Comment: There is no header, `cache_frontend_create,0.023024,0.011512,2,"2,560,880",0` is first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns are as follows:

- Timer Id: This gives the name of the block of code being executed
- Time: The time it took to complete in seconds
- Avg: The average time it took to complete in seconds
- Cnt: Short for Count. This represents the number of times this individual block ran to generate the output required
- Emalloc: The amount of memory PHP ( the programming language on which Magento runs) assigned to this single operation. This is again represented in bytes.
- RealMem: The actual amount of memory used to perform the operation.

Comment: You are describe the 3 of 5, can you explain other?